# How can i loop ip address for two routers

Tags: python-2.7

I am beginner to python and i made telnet access to two routers R1and R2 through( `for x in range  (1,3) :`) loop and i want to include in the same loop, loop back interfaces for each router example:
R1 only have  interface  loopback 1 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255
R2 only have interface  loopback 2  2.2.2 255.255.255.255
I successfully created the loop back interfaces but am not able to assign the ip address for each one .

```
import getpass

import sys

import telnetlib



user = raw_input("Enter your Telnet Username: ")

password = getpass.getpass()



for n in range (1,3):

    HOST = "10.1.1." + str(n)

    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

    tn.read_until("Username: ")

    tn.write(user + "\n")

    if password:

        tn.read_until("Password: ")

        tn.write(password + "\n")

    tn.write("config t\n")

    tn.write("int l " + str(n) +"\n")

    tn.write("ip add  str(n) . str(n) . str(n)  . str(n)    255.255.255.255 \n")

    tn.write("router eigrp 1\n")

    tn.write("net 0.0.0.0\n")

    tn.write("end\n")

    tn.write("sh ip int br\n")

    tn.write("exit\n")



    print tn.read_all()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the result of:

```
tn.write("ip add  str(n) . str(n) . str(n)  . str(n)    255.255.255.255 \n")
```

Will be a string: ip add  str(n) . str(n) . str(n)  . str(n)    255.255.255.255

Change that line to:

```
tn.write("ip add " + str(n) + "." + str(n) + "." + str(n) + "." + str(n) + " 255.255.255.255 \n")
```